# Angular XSS - Input validation

Tags: angular, xss

This question is to understand if input validation is required in the following scenario:

We have an Angular form that connects to a Java backend. The form has a number of free text areas. The business do not want to block any standard ASCII character from the input (e.g. >, <, ~). But the Security side, suggests using a whitelist to prevent XSS attacks.

From what we understand Angular provides Output encoding by default, as long as the data binding is not done using DOM manipulation (i.e., if it uses interpolation/attr binding/ngModel). So, would there be any reason to block the <, > characters if no DOM manipulation is happening?
In other words, is it ok to have a whitelist that encompasses all ASCII characters on a standard EN-US keyboard including the < and > chars?